# When using blender as a video editor, it is making all of my images dark

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, color

I have been using blender as a video editor for a video project I am working on. A large part of this project is taking images and showing them while someone is talking in the background.

My problem is for some reason the images are being darkened. Picture below. I tried looking through the properties and couldn't see anything obvious to change. I have also imported a video to use that *seems* unchanged, although it is hard to tell. Thanks in advance.

[image: Original lighted image]

[image: Altered darker image]

Comment: I've tried changing the color space of the images strip, and this does something, if I change that to filmic log, it look brighter, and a little more similar to the original, but oversaturated.

Comment: If you are using strictly sRGB based material and not Cycles material encoded with Filmic Log, change your view to the unfortunately titled “Standard”.

Comment: @troy_s When you say "change your view to" are you talking about the source > color space option for the slide? I have that set to sRGB and that is resulting in the dimmed behavior above.

Comment: No. In the Colour Management panel of properties, where Display Device, View, and Look are listed. The Colour Space on the image buffer itself describes what encoding the image buffer is using, and it should not be changed away from what it actually is.

Comment: ever figure this out? it's making all of my images lighter..